# list printing in formatted string in python

Tags: python

In python to print a formatted string with ints and strings, I'd usually do :

```
print '%d %d - %s' %(x,y, mystr)
```

Is there anything similar for printing out a list? I have:

```
L= [1,0,0]
name = 'V'
```

and I want the output to be :

```
v(1,0,0)
```

Is there anything similar to %d for list objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want complete control how the list gets rendered, you'll have to format it separately.

In your case, the code would be something like:

```
items = [1,0,0]
name = 'V'
formatted = '%s(%s)' % (
    name,
    ','.join(str(it) for it in items)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always subclass `list`, then overwrite the `repr` function to print the `list` in whatever format you want, like so:

```
In [1]: class MyList(list):
            def repr(self):
                return ", ".join(["%s" % s for s in self])

In [2]: x = MyList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [3]: x
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [4]: print x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [5]: print "abc__ %s __def" % x
abc__ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] __def

In [6]: y = MyList()

In [7]: y.append(55)

In [8]: y.append("abc")

In [9]: y
Out[9]: [55, 'abc']

In [10]: print "ZZZ -- %s -- ZZZ" % y
ZZZ -- [55, 'abc'] -- ZZZ
```